# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.1.0.0'

Tags: botframework

I'm facing this issue while trying to call my bot via directline:

[image]

As you can see on the image below, my webapi bot project is using the version 5.2.4.0, but according to the log error, the Microsoft.Bot.Conector is trying to use an old version of it ? 
Does anybody have a clue on how can I solve it ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a binding redirect?

Comment: A binding redirect worket fine. thanks @EricDahlvang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a binding redirection as @Eric suggested worked fine.
[image]